# Dotfuscator Bad RVA

Tags: c#, debugging, dotfuscator

I've just started using Dotfuscator and I've hit a brick wall right from the start, when Ibuild my project Dotfuscator says:

```
Writing Assemblies...

Bad RVA found: 46
Build Error.
```

I can't find any mention of this problem anywhere online.

My project is split into several parts, a core library project and several applications which depend on the library project. I'm only trying to obfuscate the library project at the moment. For input assemblies I have just pointed Dotfuscator at the Library.dll in the bin/x86/Release folder.

Am I doing something wrong here, or have I really hit a previously unknown bug in Dotfuscator?

**Edit:** I just noticed the "Investigate only" option, which I just ran against the project and it seems to work just fine:

```
Build Finished.
Build Statistics    Total  Renamed  Percent Renamed
Types:                271       63          23.25 %
Methods:             1609      672          41.77 %
Fields:              1099      852          77.53 %
Dotfuscator Community Edition cannot rename generic types or methods.
```

Comment: Does this belong on Programmers and not SO?

Comment: I don't think so, build tools such as Dotfuscator are just another part of the development process. Imo a question like "Which obfuscation tool should I use" might want to go on programmers, but not a question like this.

Comment: I think it's ok here.  It is a specific technical question about a programming product.

Answer (score 0):

An RVA is a component of the assembly's metadata, and stands for "Relative Virtual Address." It's a number stored in the assembly header, pointing to some virtual address in the assembly.  In Dotfuscator, each RVA is checked for validity as it's processed by a given subsystem (not all subsystems process RVAs though), and this check will fail if

A) No section headers were found in the assembly metadata but RVAs were found, or

B) The RVA points to an address that falls prior to the last virtual address of all found section headers.

Generally, neither of these things should happen.  Check to see if there are post-build behaviors that may have altered the library assembly.  You may also want to try running [PEVerify](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62bwd2yd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to see if your library checks out alright.  Failure to pass PEVerify doesn't mean code won't run, but it can interfere with obfuscation (or any processing of the assembly metadata).  If PEVerify passes, you've got me :)  Perhaps inspect the metadata manually to see if either condition A or B above are being hit.